# Find exercises to practice vector calculus

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis, book-recommendation, vector-fields

I studied vector calculus like a month ago, and now I'd like to practice to remember it. Could someone please recommend me a book or a resource to practice?

Comment: You could try to do the problems in your book or try to prove some theorems there.

Comment: A quick Google search will give probably literally hundreds of Vector Calculus past exams - or as @SiKucing suggested - even on this here website!

Comment: This might fit better in math educators’ stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

One useful and free resource with available solutions to the exercises that comes to my mind is [Paul's online calculus notes](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/CalcIII.aspx).

Hope this helps.